# Regex to match time with . or : and a possible single number start

Tags: python, regex

Im trying to use regex(python) to match the time in a string while accounting for user discrepancies such as am pm or capitols, a single number to start(9:30) and use of a `.` or `:` . I am very close with the following:

`(\d{1,2}(:|.)\d{2}\s?(?:AM|PM|am|pm))`

but when using https://pythex.org/ to check it returns two matches for most strings, example string:

`@Stand-up Bot at 4.30am every day`

The issue is that I'm getting two matches, one for the time `4.30am` which is great but I'm also getting a second match for the separating character in between the numbers `.` or `:`.

How can I update the regex to return just the exact time match and not the separating character too?

Thanks

Comment: `(:|.)` => `(?::|\.)` => `[:.]`. The whole => `(?i)\d{1,2}[:.]\d{2}\s?[ap]m`

Comment: thank you, was losing my mind

Comment: You are actually getting 1 match. The issue is that you are capturing 2 groups, due to the 2 sets of capturing parentheses `()`: one set surrounds the whole regex, and the second surrounds the `:|.`. You should make the second one non-capturing using `(?:)` like you did with the AM-PM stuff, like this: `(?::|.)`.

Also, `.` is a special character in a regex that matches anything (e.g. `4X30am`), so you should escape it like this: `:|\.`.